# how communicate between 2 users of a website?

Tags: yii2

can anyone suggest basic logic how to communicate between users of a site.
I have a website made in yii2 framework. suppose I have user A and user B. I want to enable one way communication between them. If A is admin then only he can send him a card eg. "these are the task you have to do it today". No other user can see this card except user B(Receiver)? 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension [thyseus/yii2-message](https://github.com/thyseus/yii2-message).

It gives you

- a little message box per user
- the ability to create and send messages to other users
- a badge for the menu indicating there are new messages
- the option for every user to forward messages by email to users

I used in a project and it works very well.

Comment: where should I get its demo?

Comment: on above given link there is migration command .. I run that command it gives...PHP Warning:  Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'The configuration for
the "user" component must contain a "class" element.'

in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2-my-app2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\ServiceLocator.php:204

Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2-my-app2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\ServiceLocator.php(260):
yii\di\ServiceLocator->set('user', Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2-my-ap

Comment: It is recommended to have the extension Yii2-user installed when working with Yii2-messages (you need users which can send messages of course). Check is this is installed correctly. If the problem persists, raise an issue for https://github.com/thyseus/yii2-message

Comment: 1)$ composer require thyseus/yii2-message
2)$ php yii migrate/up --migrationPath=@vendor/thyseus/yii2-message/migrations... fromfirst command yii2-message installed suceessfully... but second command gives.. do you know solution for this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48862736/yii2-migration-command-gives-warning-how-to-fix-it